# How to install custom protobuf packages in AWS Glue schema registry?

Tags: protocol-buffers, aws-glue

i am thinking of using AWS Glue's schema registry to host all of my protobuf models. I am currently following this [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/introducing-protocol-buffers-protobuf-schema-support-in-amazon-glue-schema-registry/). In their `Employee.proto` i see that they are importing packages from `google` and `gsr` like this:

```
package gsr.proto.post;
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/type/money.proto";
```

I was able to add the sample `Employee.proto` to my schema registry just fine. However, I am running into import errors when I try to import my own protobuf package. Here is my sample `.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.my_repo.message.event;

import "com/my_repo/message/event/enums/Type.proto";

message Message {

  message Alert {
    string id = 1;
    uint64 account_id = 2;
    com.my_repo.message.event.enums.Type type = 3;
  }
}
```

but i get the following error messages in my AWS console:

```
One schema failed to create
The following schema failed to create: "Message"
Here is the most recent error message: Schema definition of PROTOBUF data format is invalid: unable to find com/my_repo/message/event/enums/Type.proto
```

Granted, I have not yet added `Type.proto` schema to the registry yet but i think the issue is that i need to add my package first. But i cannot seem to find a way to do that. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance